# Leer un arreglo floats de un archivo para mostrarlo en pantalla y seleccionar uno para modificarlo en C++

Tags: c++

Buen día, debo hacer un programa que me almacene N temperaturas en un archivo TXT, mostrarlas en pantalla, sacar promedio, entre otros. Todo compila bien con respecto al ingreso de los datos en el archivo, pero mi problema es que cuando quiero leer los datos del archivo y mostrarlos en la consola (`void modificarArchivo()`) para realizar la modificación o usar los datos para realizar X función, la consola se queda en blanco. He visto muchos tutoriales y ejemplos, pero todos usan caracteres o frases para la lectura y escritura. Mi pregunta es, ¿cuál es el error en esa función y que debo hacer para corregirla?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void linea(int longitud){ 
    string caracter = "";
    for(int i=0; i<longitud; i++){
        caracter += "=";
    }
    cout << caracter << endl;
}

void encabezado(string titulo){
    linea(40); //40 "="
    cout<<"\t"<<titulo<<endl;
    linea(40); //40 "="
}

void crearArchivo(int cantidad){
    ofstream Temperatura;
    float temps[cantidad];
    Temperatura.open("ListeTemperarutas.txt", ios::out);
    if (Temperatura.fail()){
        cout<<"No se pudo abrir el abrir";
        exit(1);
    }
    Temperatura<<"\t*** Lista de Temperatura ***\n\n";
    for (int i = 1; i <= cantidad; ++i){
        cout<<"Ingrese temperatura "<<i<<": ";
        cin>>temps[i];
        Temperatura<<"Temperatura " <<i<<"....."<<temps[i]<<" grados"<<endl;
    }
    Temperatura.close();
}

void modificarArchivo(){
    ifstream Temperatura; //Abrir el archivo
    ofstream auxTemp; // Auxiliar
    float temps[100];
    int i=1;
    Temperatura.open("ListeTemperarutas.txt", ios::in);
    if (Temperatura.fail() && auxTemp.fail() ){
        cout<<"No se pudo abrir ningun archivo...";
        exit(1);
    }
    while(!Temperatura.eof()){ 
        Temperatura>>temps[i];
        i++;
    }
    //Para mostrar la lista de temperaturas
    for(int x = 1; x<100; x++){ 
        cout<<"Temperatura "<<x<<" :"<<temps[x]<<endl;
    }
    Temperatura.close();
    auxTemp.close();
}

int main(){
    system("color f0");
    int opc;

    do{
        system("cls");

        cout<<"\n\tLista de Temperaturas\n\n";
        cout<<" 1. Crear archivo actual para ingresar temperaturas."<<endl;
        cout<<" 2. Modificar datos del archivo actual."<<endl;
        cout<<" 3. Mostrar promedios."<<endl;
        cout<<" 4. Mostrar archivo historico."<<endl;
        cout<<" 5. Salir."<<endl;
        cout<<" Opcion: ";
        cin>>opc;   

        switch(opc){
            case 1:
                system("cls");
                int n;
                encabezado("Ingreso de temperaturas");
                cout<<"\nCuantas temperaturas desea registrar: \n";
                cin>>n; 
                crearArchivo(n);            
            break;  
            case 2:
                system("cls");
                encabezado("Modificando el archivo actual");
                modificarArchivo();
            break;
        }
    }while(opc != 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En `crearArchivo` guardas texto. Caracteres alfanuméricos y signos de puntuación.

En `modificarArchivo` solo intentas leer float. No puedes porque al crear el archivo no escribiste solo números.

Frente a esto, la mejor opción es escribir y leer solo números.

Sino seguir escribiendo el archivo de la misma manera pero ignorando lo que no sea un número.

---

Además:

- Recuerda que la numeración en los arreglos comienza del 0 y no del 1.
- `auxTemp` no tiene uso. Considera quitarlo. Tampoco me parece buena idea llamar la función `eof` sobre un archivo que no está abierto.
- A la hora de leer el archivo, deberías ver qué no haya errores. En caso de que los haya debes limpiar los bits de estado y decidir qué hacer. En este caso solo te interesan los números así que probablemente quieras ignorar lo que no sea un número.

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
  while (!Temperatura.eof()){ 
      if (Temperatura>>temps[i]) {
          i++;
      } else {
          // Limpia el estado de error
          Temperatura.clear();
          // Consume un caracter
          Temperatura.get();
          // O si prefieres puedes consumir hasta el siguiente espacio
          // Temperatura.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ' ');
      }
  }
```

Documentación de [`get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) y [`ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).